# Find lag in group matching a condition

Tags: r, dplyr, conditional-statements, lag, lead

I need for each group of ID's to find the last (lag) of another column, but not just the last, but the last matching the condition.

My problem is, I don't know how to add the condition to the row.

My data and desired output:
[image]

I've tried

```
  df  %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   arrange(activity_nr) %>% 
   mutate(desired_output = if_else(is.na(matched) &
                             lag(event) != "hospital", 
                           lag(event), NA)) `
```

But the condition of `lag(event) != "hospital"` is not correct, since it only matches if event is not hospital - what I want is for it to find the last non-hospital event.

I've also tried

```
 df  %>% 
       group_by(ID) %>% 
       arrange(activity_nr) %>% 
       mutate(desired_output = if_else(is.na(matched) &
                               str_detect(event, "1"), 
                               lag(event), NA))
```

and

```
df  %>% 
           group_by(ID) %>% 
           arrange(activity_nr) %>% 
           mutate(desired_output = if_else(is.na(matched),
                                   lag(str_detect(event, "1")), NA))
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), event = c("108", "hospital", "hospital", 
"hospital", "hospital", "108", "110", "hospital", "hospital", 
"110", "hospital", "hospital", "107", "107", "105", "105", "hospital", 
"hospital", "110", "110"), event_type = c("start", "start", "end", 
"start", "end", "end", "start", "start", "end", "end", "start", 
"end", "start", "end", "start", "end", "start", "end", "start", 
"end"), activity_nr = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 
8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7), activity_id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2), activity_type = c("housing", 
"hospital", "hospital", "hospital", "hospital", "housing", "housing", 
"hospital", "hospital", "housing", "hospital", "hospital", "housing", 
"housing", "housing", "housing", "hospital", "hospital", "housing", 
"housing"), matched = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 107, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 110, NA, NA), `Desired output` = c(NA, 
NA, 108, NA, 108, NA, NA, NA, 110, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Comment: Please use `dput()` to share a reproducible example of your data

Comment: Thank you @Sotos, I didn't know dput()

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I actually found the solution.

Here you go:

```
df  %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>% 
   arrange(activity_nr) %>% 
   mutate(temp = event,
         temp = ifelse(temp == "hospital", NA, temp)) %>% 
   fill(temp, .direction = "down") %>% 
   mutate(desired_output = case_when(is.na(matched)
                                      ~ temp,
                                      TRUE ~ desired_output))
```